# Is there no need for memory allocation when using strings in C?

Tags: c, string

I had to work with the open-source code from [mmc-utils](https://github.com/mhei/mmc-utils/blob/master/mmc_cmds.c) some time ago and found this function:

```
int do_erase(int nargs, char **argv)
{
    int dev_fd, ret;
    char *print_str;
    __u8 ext_csd[512], checkup_mask = 0;
    __u32 arg, start, end;

    ...

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "legacy") == 0) {
        arg = 0x00000000;
        print_str = "Legacy Erase";
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "discard") == 0) {
        arg = 0x00000003;
        print_str = "Discard";
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "secure-erase") == 0) {
        print_str = "Secure Erase";
        checkup_mask = EXT_CSD_SEC_ER_EN;
    }

    ...

    if ((checkup_mask & ext_csd[EXT_CSD_SEC_FEATURE_SUPPORT]) !=
                            checkup_mask) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not supported in %s\n",
            print_str, argv[4]);
        ret = -ENOTSUP;
        goto out;
    }

out:
    printf(" %s %s!\n\n", print_str, ret ? "Failed" : "Succeed");
    close(dev_fd);
    return ret;
}
```

What i do not understand, is how this function works without any memory allocation for `print_str`. It is neither on the stack nor in heap. Sure there is a pointer for the strings prepared in the stack, but there is no magic compiler stack allocation at runtime in C - is there?

Compiling `mmc-utils` works fine and i ran the code several times before without issues. Is there someone that can explain me the arcane witchcraft at work here?

Comment: This is no witchcraft. String literals are just stored in a (typically readonly) segment; they effectively have static storage duration. You can imagine them as being stored as constant global character arrays for the most part.

Comment: Don't forget that your program is also in memory. The strings are part of your program, and there can be a pointer to them. The memory in which your program (including your constant strings) resides is allocated and freed by the operating system when your program execution starts/ends.

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Comment: Perhaps the surprise is that "stack" and "heap" are not the only places where things can be stored.  The compiler has more options for "static" storage that lives through the whole program execution.

Comment: @BoP That is precisely what confused me. In all honesty i did not know that C allowed to just point to some String literal in the code section. And at this point i do not get, what the benefit of this is, compared to just printing where the pointer is assigned ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your code, it is turned into a blob which you then store on disk (the executable). To execute it, you load it into the memory and start executing machine instructions it contains. If some data is known at compile time, such as the `"Discard"` sequence of characters it can also be embedded in the executable, next to the instructions. During compilation, machine code is often stored in the `.text` sections, while data such as strings is stored in `.data` or `.rodata` and other related sections. Sections are later inserted into appropriate segments, which are what eventually ends up stored on your disk and later loaded into memory.

When your compiler sees a string literal such as `"Discard"` it understands it as "This data is known in advance at compile time, allocate enough space for the string + null terminator in the executable and store this data here". At the same time, when you assign such a string literal as a right-side value, it evaluates to the address of the string in memory.

```c
char* print_str = "Discard";
```

Above statement does both things: during compilation it allocates memory for the string in the executable and stores it there, and during execution it assigns the address of the string to the variable print_str. You can use the `strings` command to show all the printable strings embedded in the file (those include data that is used by the program as well as other data and metadata inserted by the compiler/present in the executable file format. It should display the string "Discard" among other things too).

You can use `gdb` to examine memory regions used by your program and where do they come from. If you run your program with `gdb` and execute the `info proc mappings` command from inside the gdb shell it will show you a list of memory ranges. Some of those may be marked as stack or heap, and will not be file-based, but others will come from either the executable itself or any dynamic libraries that it uses. You should see at least one memory region that came from your executable that has no X permission (execute) which means that it does not contain machine code (it would be useless without the permission to execute it). Such regions often contain readable and/or writable data.

> there is no magic compiler stack allocation at runtime in C - is there?

Actually, stack is a very easy method of memory allocation. Aside from system-imposed memory limits or stack size limits there is nothing stopping you from allocating more memory on it at any given time (at least on x86 PC). The only disadvantage of stack is that it is local to the current function, so the value will be lost once it returns. This of course is a big problem here, but in other situations it allows, for instance, arrays of user-defined or in any other form known-at-runtime size:

```c
size_t array_size = user_input_size(); // The array_size variable is unknown until runtime
char arr[array_size]; // But this is still legal C, just grow the stack space a bit (up to a limit defined by the OS)
```

Comment: Thank you very much: I had no Idea that i was allowed to just point and read from some arbitrary  place in the code section. But now that i think about it, i guess a function pointer is not that different? Just pointing to executables.

Comment: msaw328, "cast a function pointer to a uint8_t pointer and printf bytes of machine code one after another." --> that is undefined behavior.  Even the pointer sizes may differ.  @led "I had no Idea that i was allowed to just point and read from some arbitrary place in the code section." --> not quite.

Comment: `char arr[array_size];` is a [variable length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), available in C99 and optionally thereafter, so sometimes _legal_.

Comment: I did not check whether it was UB or not, my bad, i removed the comment about pointer casting.

Answer (score 4):

In C all literal strings (like `"Discard"`) are really arrays of characters (including the null-terminator) stored somewhere in memory by the compiler and the OS. Its memory have already been allocated so there's no need for you to allocate the memory yourself.

As other arrays, they also decay to pointers to their first element. So an assignment like `print_str = "Discard"` will make the variable `print_str` point to the first character in the string-array that contains the string `"Discard"`.

In code it will be something similar to this:

```
char discard_string[] = { 'D', 'i', 's', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'd', '\0' };
char *print_str;

// Other code...

print_str = &discard_str[0];
```

---

One important thing to note: While literal strings are not constant, it's not allowed to modify them. They are, in effect, *read only*.

Any attempt to modify a literal string leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Isn't a literal placed in ROM, hence why it's read only?

Comment: @BasVisscher Modern PC systems seldom have "ROM" in the classical sense. Instead it's typically placed in the code section together with other constant and non-modifiable data. The OS then loads this section into virtual memory pages that are marked as read-only.

Comment: @BasVisscher IIRC it need not be placed in ROM (`.rodata`), but it usually is. I'd add `static const` before `char discard_string[]` though to make it more clear what properties string literals usually have (and that you may in particular not attempt to mutate string literals).

Comment: @BasVisscher On embedded systems with flash memory acting a true non-volatile ROM, they are placed in ROM indeed. On PC there's just RAM.

Comment: Right, I often work with microcontrollers. Modern systems are quite different ofc. BTW, If you try to write to a literal, you will get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @BasVisscher And well, there's a bit of history... back in the dark ages certain C programs chose to purposely modify a string literal since it was after all stored in RAM. When C was standardized this practice was kind of outlawed ("undefined behavior") but the ISO C89 committee was too cowardly to go all the way and turn string literals into type `const char[]`, because that would break all pre-standard rotten code that did modify string literals. Whereas in C++ they were always `const char[]`, which is the only sensible thing. This should have been fixed in C too, like 30 years ago...

Comment: That explains things, legacy... :) We have a lot of that flying about here as well. Nowadays, we primarily write in C++ for our embedded devices.

Comment: @BasVisscher Ah well, MCU's are a different thing, where ROM might still exists (either as "classic" ROM or as FLASH). Then it's still not that different, the literal strings can still be put together with code and other constant data, but programmed into the ROM on the target system.

Comment: @Lundin: The pre-standard code that modified string literals generally does break. What they were preserving was the ability of the pre-standard code that happened to not be `const`-correct (but did not modify the literals) to continue compiling without having to add the `const` modifier to all those declarations. Not saying they made the right decision, but it wasn't about preserving *broken* code (which broke on most compilers when they started using `.rodata` for storage).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Kind of... but there were members in the C89 committee demanding that their rotten code should still be valid. C99 rationale v5.10 chapter 6.4.5: "However, string literals do not have the type _array of const char_
10 in order to avoid the problems of pointer type checking, particularly with library functions, since assigning a _pointer to const char_ to a plain _pointer to char_ is not valid. Those members of the C89 Committee who insisted that string literals should be modifiable were content to have this practice designated a common extension (see §J.5.5)."

Comment: @ShadowRanger This "must preserve rotten code" philosophy remains to this day. J5.5 remains unchanged in C23, the same as it was written in C89. Sure annex J isn't normative and J5 is about common extensions, but still - they should have fixed const correctness 30 years ago. Because not follow const correctness almost always means there's bugs or major design flaws. They likely _would_ have fixed it just like C++ did, if not for those rotten-code-huggers in the C89 committee.

Comment: @@Lundin Of course it was G.5.5 rather than J.5.5 back in C89 days!

Answer (score 2):

> how this function works without any memory allocation for `print_str` (?)

`print_str` is a `char *`.  It is a *pointer* (maybe 2, 4, 8, ... bytes), not a *string*.  With `print_str = "Legacy Erase"` and others, the pointer is assigned the address of the first character of the *string literal* `"Legacy Erase"`.  That *string literal* is a compile time array of characters.  Then `print_str` points to a *string*.  The "allocation" happened at compile time (or at the start of run-time - whatever model works for you).

IMO, it is easier to understand if one first remembers that an array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.  In C, a *string* is "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".  *Strings* are often stored in *arrays*.

Comment: You are right in pointing out the difference, I know how pointers work in C. My problem was, that the string is neither stored in heap nor on the stack. Just pointing to ROM with `= "String"` is a first for me. I changed it in my original post, so the problem i had is more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one form of assembly for the C program.

```
int main() { const char * const s = "Hello World\n"; write(1, s, 12); }
```

```
section .data

msg1 db "Hello, World!",10,0
msg1Len equ $-msg1-1

section .text

global main

main:
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
mov rax, 1 ; write (1)
mov rdi, 1 ; to stdout (1)
mov rsi, msg1
mov rdx, msg1Len ; length of string

syscall ; perform the system call write
```

The string "Hello World!\0" is stored in the .data segment along with the zero terminator and the length.
That string has an address. Put that address in a pointer and the system call will begin to read from that address until it finds '\0'.

So what is stored is a string inside the binary with a well defined address and pointers can point to that address.

Comment: Would be interesting to know, if a regular compiler allocates only once in the `.data` section, when two strings are the same. Like ` char* s1 = "abc"; char* s2 = "abc";`. I guess it would not violate the _as-if_ rule. If i find something, i will post below.

Comment: that would be a basic optimization by the compiler writers

Comment: @led MSVC has the [`/GF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gf-eliminate-duplicate-strings) compiler option to enable *"string pooling"*. It is in effect when the `/O1` or `/O2` optimization level is used. Regardless of that, the question is conflating two distinct concepts: *"Pointer values"* and *"strings"*. Pointer values are just values, like the number 42. Using them doesn't require freestore allocation.